# PHP / DOM method to change image-paths that are not within <pre> or <code> tags, without JavaScript

Tags: php, image, function, dom, path

**Tasks:**

1. All occurrences must be replaced with the value of constant `DEVICE` which I have already per-defined using some other function. **BUT** should not replace from the code wrapped within the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.
2. This task need to be accomplished without the use of any JavaScript.

**Sample Mark-up:**

```
<div class="wrapper">

<img src="img/demo/desktop-img/sample1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="image">
<img src="img/demo/desktop-img/sample2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="image">

<pre>
<img src="img/demo/desktop-img/sample1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="image">
<img src="img/demo/desktop-img/sample2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="image">
</pre>

<code>
<img src="img/demo/desktop-img/sample1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="image">
<img src="img/demo/desktop-img/sample2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="image">
</code>

</div>
```

I tried the following but it is replacing the occurrences within the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags too and that is exactly what should not happen. I am using PHP as my programming language.

`$content = str_replace('/desktop-img/', '/' . DEVICE . '-img/', $content);`

**I even tried the following but no luck**

```
<?php
function changeImagePaths ($content) { // content here comes as string via some other functon.
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('[self::img][not(ancestor::pre) and not(ancestor::code)]');

    foreach( $nodes as $node ) {

        // What is the correct way to retrive all image-paths
        // that are not wrapped within <pre> or <code> tags and how to use them in the code?

        $node->nodeValue = str_replace('desktop-img', DEVICE, $node->nodeValue);
    }

    $content = $dom->saveHTML();

    return $content;
}
?>
```

**Challenge:**

I think it should be possible using the DOM method but I am not able to figure out the correct syntax.

I am very new to programming hence still in the learning process. Please be gentle and illustrate you answer with code examples for easy understanding.

**My Questions:**

1. What should be the correct syntax for DOM method?
2. Is using DOM the correct way?
3. Are there going to be any challenges / performance hits, using the DOM method?
4. Is there any other better way of doing it without using JavaScript?

Comment: srt_replace should be str_replace

Comment: @allen213 Thanks. Updated with correction.

Comment: Thought: Start from the root element, recursively walk through child nodes, but in case of `<pre>`, skip.

Comment: @Passerby may I kindly request you to convert you thought into code syntax. As I mentioned, I am very new to programming and will be very difficult to understand without examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick work, so it may not look nice, but hopefully you get the idea.

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/B9rgp)

```
function walkDOM($node)
{
    if($node->nodeName=="pre" || $node->nodeName=="code")
    {
        return;
    }
    elseif($node->nodeName=="img")
    {
        $node->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->nodeValue=str_replace('desktop-img','mobile-img',$node->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->nodeValue);
    }
    elseif($node->hasChildNodes())
    {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $child)
        {
            walkDOM($child);
        }
    }
}
function changeImagePath($html)
{
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $root=$dom->documentElement;
    walkDOM($root);
    $dom->formatOutput=false;
    return $dom->saveHTML($root);
}
```

The thought is to recursively walk through the DOM tree, skip every `<pre>` and `<code>`, and change all `<img>` that encountered.

This is pretty straight forward, but you may notice that since you treat it as HTML, DOM automatically add some tags to "fulfill" it, and format it in a (IMO) quite strange manner.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is your friend:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//img[not(ancestor::pre) and not(ancestor::code)]') as $img){
  $img->setAttribute('src', 'foo');
}
```

Comment: That's not how this works. If you need someone to write the code for you, then you should consider hiring someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path1='C:/ff/ss.html';
$file=file_get_contents($path1);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($file);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
//extract img src path from the html page 
foreach ($links as $link) { 
    $re= $link->getAttribute('src');
    $a[]=$re;
}
$oldpth=explode('/',$path1);
$c=count($oldpth)-1;
$fname=$oldpth[$c];
$pth=array_slice($oldpth,0,$c);
$cpth=implode('/',$pth);
foreach($a as $v) {
    if(is_file ($cpth.'/'.$v)) { 
        $c=explode('/',$v);
        $c[0]="xyz007";
        $f=implode('/',$c);
        $file=str_replace ($v,$f,$file);
    }
}
$path2='D:/mail/newpath/';
$wnew=fopen($path2.$fname,'w+');
fwrite($wnew,$file);
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your answer? all these lines aren't necessary